# How to disply only first 100 character from model in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

This is my **Model**

```
function get_news(){
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('articles');
        $this->db->where('status' , 0);
        $this->db->limit(6);
        $this->db->order_by('created', 'desc');
        return $this->db->get()->result();  
    }
```

My table **arcticles**

```
id----title----body----status---created
```

Now here on the column **body** I want to disply only 100 characters where should I edite on view, controller, or this model on up.

Comment: You need to strip the body to 100 character or you want to fetch the data that having only 100 character long?

Comment: yes i want to fetch only 100, on the body there is more but only 100 character of that i want not all

Comment: substr is used in your tpl. No need of using it in query fetch

Comment: echo substr($result->body, 0, 100); to show only 100 characters

Comment: that's was right @Sibiraj PR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use substr

```
$content = substr($str, 0, 100);
```

Comment: where i should use this on model or view

Comment: U can do it at either place. If you are passing a final array from model then you can synthesize it there itself or else view is the final place where you can add this logic.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`substr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

```
function get_news() {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('articles');
    $this->db->where('status' , 0);
    $this->db->limit(6);
    $this->db->order_by('created', 'desc');
    return substr($this->db->get()->result(), 0, 100); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i always use a `function` when i need to cut a string at certain character without cutting the last word itself. This function will take care of that by decreasing character if needed

```
function strSelect( $myString, $maxLength ) {
$out = "";
$s = explode( " ",$myString );
for( $i = 0, $cs = count( $s ); $i < $cs; $i++ ) {
    $out .= $s[$i]." ";
    if( isSet( $s[$i+1] ) && ( strlen( $out ) + strlen( $s[$i+1] ) ) > $maxLength ) {
        break;
    }
}
return rtrim( $out );
```

}

and then you can call like

```
return strSelect(($this->db->get()->result()), 100);
```

or you can simply cut at given number with [**`substr`** (documentation here)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) function

```
substr(($this->db->get()->result()), 0, 100);
```